# How to justify this statement?

Tags: complex-analysis, power-series, analyticity, holomorphic-functions, analytic-functions

Let $f$ a holomorphic function in $\mathbb{D}(0,1)$ such that $f(z)=\sum_{n\ge 0}a_n z^n$. Then apparentely we can deduce that for all $r\in [0,1[$, $n\ge1$ : $\int \limits_{0}^{2\pi} \overline{f(r\exp(i\theta))}\exp(-in\theta)\mathrm{d}\theta=0$.

I thought that it was a Cauchy formula but $\bar{f}$ is not necessarily holomorphic.

Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Conjugation is linear and continuous, so 
$$
\int  _{0}^{2\pi} \overline{f(r\exp(i\theta))}\exp(-in\theta)\mathrm{d}\theta
=\overline{\int  _{0}^{2\pi}  {f(r\exp(i\theta))}\exp(in\theta)\mathrm{d}\theta}
$$

Comment: Moreover with that fact that $f$ is holomorphic on $\mathbb{D}(0,1)$, the Cauchy theorem on the circle gives that the integral is equal to $0$ and after using conjugation's properties we get the result right ?

Comment: Yes. $\ \ \ \ $

Comment: Perfect ! Thanks !

Comment: In the Cauchy theorem, I don't have the parameter $n$. It gives : $\int  _{0}^{2\pi}  {f(r\exp(i\theta))}ri\exp(i\theta)\mathrm{d}\theta=\int  _{0}^{2\pi}  {f(r\exp(i\theta))}\exp(i\theta)\mathrm{d}\theta=0$...

Comment: You have $$\int  _{0}^{2\pi}  {f(r\exp(i\theta))}\exp(in\theta)\mathrm{d}\theta=\tfrac1{i\,r^n}\int  _{0}^{2\pi}  {f(r\exp(i\theta))}r^{n-1}\exp(i(n-1)\theta)\,ri\exp(i\theta)\,\mathrm{d}\theta,$$ so you are applying Cauchy's theorem to the analytic function $z^{n-1}f(z)$.